# Thread start in Form1() crashing program on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hey guys, I'm getting a really strange error. I have a program that needs to run a thread on startup, and for some reason when I do `myThread.Start()` in `Form1()`  it will crash with "program is not working" (But only on Windows Server, not on my local machine!). However,  if I put the same code under `button1_Start()` it works no problem. What gives?

Any ideas?
Thank you.

EDIT 
A little extra information: In my thread I have a line of code that uses invoke

```
Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("Updating {0}..\n", DateTime.Now))));
```

And for some reason the crashing goes away after I make the thread sleep for 2 seconds before it starts executing. Am I using the right method to execute code on the app startup?

Comment: What does the thread do?

Comment: Are you accessing some resources from your thread? If so, what type(s) of resource(s)?

Comment: When you say *put the same code under button1_Start*, do you mean that you move the starting of the thread to that method, or that you move the contents of the thread to that method. How about you just show us the form constructor, the code in your thread, and how button1_Start would look like? ie. show us the code?

Comment: can you post your code??

Comment: I mean I move the thread start from button1_Start() to Form1(). In the thread I do a lot of things, one being the Invoke method, and the others going as far as using HTMLAgilityPack. It's very long code so I don't think posting it is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, this is a guess, you haven't given nearly enough information in your question to give you any definitive answers.

I doubt it has anything to do with Windows Server 2008, but probably more with the fact that the server has more CPU cores and/or a faster processor than your development machine.

If you, in the thread tries to either access the form through a variable, or you try to invoke back to the thread that owns the form, you will crash on a fast computer.

Why?

In the first case, the variable has not yet been set. The following code:

```
var fm = new Form1();
```

here, `fm` will not be set before the constructor has returned. If your thread has already tried to access the form through `fm`, that variable is `null`.

In the second case, the constructor is not responsible for showing the form, that happens afterwards. Many controls postpone actually allocating a handle until they are asked to draw themselves, and thus if the thread tries to do stuff to a control before that, it will crash.

You should instead start your thread from `Form_Load`.

Comment: That was bang on the money! I just threw the code into Form_Load and it works perfectly. Nice =)

Answer (score 0):

In our company we had the same symptom on an application that spawned a bitmap async loading that used COM - only on W2008.

The problem turned out to be:

- we used a COM object from that thread (which was STA)
- only on W2008 initialization of the object could not complete in time
- thread started working before the COM was ready and getting error

I don't know why only on W2008, but our hack was to move the start of the thread from the constructor to the actual point where the thread work was needed.